# About Map in Golang Programming Language

Tags: dictionary, go

I found the code

```
newMap := map[string]interface{}{

  "string1" : 1,
  "string2" : "hello",
  "string3" : map[string]string{
     "hello" : "hello there"
   }

}
```

My guess is that If we use interface for map as the value type, then we can insert any type to value, is it correct?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Yes, that is accurate. `interface{}` stands for "any type", not only in maps.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it has nothing specific with map. But response to your question is `yes`. You can insert anything you want inside.

Definition for empty interface from "A Tour of Go"

> An empty interface may hold values of any type. (Every type implements at least zero methods.)

Check example on [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/14)